# Randomised select in python, working unexpectedly

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the rselect  algorithm that I just learnt in class. However, cant seem to figure out where Im going wrong in the implementation. Here's my code. **EDIT **
: I tried using the info provided in the answer by David,but my code still acts weird. Here's the revised code:

```
def rselect(seq,length,i):# i is the i'th order statistic.
    if len(seq)<=1:return seq
    lo,pi,hi,loc_pi= random_partition(seq
    if loc_pi==i:return pi 
    if loc_pi>i:return rselect(lo,loc_pi-1,i) 
    elif loc_pi<i:return rselect(hi,length-loc_pi,i-loc_pi)#
from random import choice  
def random_partition(seq):
    pi =choice(seq)
    #print 'pi',pi
    loc_pi=seq.index(pi)
    print 'Location',loc_pi
    lo=[x for x in seq if x<=pi]
    hi=[x for x in seq if x>pi]
    return lo,pi,hi,len(lo)+1   #--A

def test_rselect(seq,i):
    print 'Sequence',seq
    l=len(seq)
    print 'Statistic', rselect(seq,l,i)
```

However the output is  different at different times and even right at times!. I'm a noob to both algorithms and python, any help on where Im going wrong would be much appreciated. 
Edit: Im getting different values for the ith order **statistic** each time I run the code , which is my issue
For instance each run of the code as below gives

```
Revised Output:
/py-scripts$ python quicksort.py
Sequence [54, -1, 1000, 565, 64, 2, 5]
Statistic Location 1
-1
@ubuntu:~/py-scripts$ python quicksort.py
Sequence [54, -1, 1000, 565, 64, 2, 5]
Statistic Location 5
Location 1
Location 0
-1
```

Expected output: Im expecting find the ith order statistic here.

And therefore

`test_rselect([54,-1,1000,565,64,2,5],2)` should return `5` as the **Statistic** all the time .

Any help in where Im going wrong with this implementation would be helpful.. Thanks!!
**EDIT 2**: From trying to analyse the algorithm I believe  the error lies in how I'm **returning the pivot location(loc_pi)** in line marked A. Considering the following sequence of events for the above program.

```
test_rselect( [ 55, 900, -1,10, 545, 250], 3) // call to input array 

calls rselect ([ 55, 900, -1,10, 545, 250],6,3)

    1st  call to random_partition:
        pi=545 and loc_pi=4
        lo=[55,-1,10,250,545]
        hi=[900]
    return to rselect function (lo,545,hi,6)
    here loc_pi>i: so rselect(lo,5,3)// and discard the hi part

    2nd recursive call to rselect:
    2nd recursive call to random_partition:
        call random_partition on (lo) // as 'hi' is discarded
        pi=55 loc_pi=0
        lo=[-1,10,55]
        hi=[250,545]
        return to rselect(lo,55,hi,4)
        here loc_pi>i: rselect(lo,3,3)// The pivot element is lost already as it is in 'hi' here!!
```

Any help on how I can deal with returning the location of the pivot element, in order to to gain the correct o/p would be helpful. Setting a bounty, **for an answer that clearly explains where I'm doing it wrong and how I could correct it ( great tips are welcome since I'm looking forward to learn :))**. Looking forward to great answers!

Comment: What is wrong with this? What would correct operation look like?

Comment: If it is random, than the results should theoretically always be different

Comment: Err I posted before question was complete, I think. My problem is that the program is returning different values of the ith order statistic

Comment: @Woot4Moo: There are plenty of randomized algorithms that produce deterministic results (randomness can be used to reduce expected running time or memory requirements).

Comment: What am I missing? The output is different each time (all except for the "Sequence", which is supposed to be the same because it is printed before anything is done to it- see the line `print 'Sequence',seq`. So in what way is it deterministic?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, the program is intended to compute the **i' th**order statistic using randomised selection, and quite frankly Imnot being able to figure out where Im going wrong, as the ith order statistic surely doesnt change from one run to another?

Comment: @KodeSeeker- Could you link us to a description of the rselect algorithm? Google is not helping me here.

Comment: (Also, I think this makes it clear that the problem is not the one that some other commenters and answerers understood it to be).

Comment: @DavidRobinson, you may consider it to be a variant of the one mentioned here :http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-four/

Comment: @aix that is not truly random, on account of (last I checked) there is no such thing as a computer based perfect random number generator.

Comment: @aix,@Woot4Moo,@David Robinson, the proposed solution isnt really working, can you look at the edited question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any principal error (in how you are returning the pivot or otherwise), it's just a lot of off-by-one (ore even two) confusion, plus I think you mean to compare with i on the first line of rselect, not 1.

Here's my take on it, with as little change as possible:

```
def rselect(seq,length,i):# i is the i'th order statistic.
    if len(seq)<=i:return seq
    lo,pi,hi,loc_pi= random_partition(seq)
    if loc_pi==i:return pi 
    if loc_pi>i:return rselect(lo,loc_pi,i) 
    elif loc_pi<i:return rselect(hi,length-(loc_pi+1),i-(loc_pi+1))
from random import choice  
def random_partition(seq):
    pi =choice(seq)
    lo=[x for x in seq if x<=pi]
    hi=[x for x in seq if x>pi]
    return lo,pi,hi,len(lo)-1
```

**Edit**: Here's a version that should work if there are duplicate elements. Now, I had to change some more, so I took out some stuff I found confusing in order to make it easier for myself.

```
def rselect(seq,i):# i is the i'th order statistic.
    if len(seq)<=i:return seq
    lo,pi,hi= random_partition(seq)
    if i < len(lo):return rselect(lo,i) 
    if i < len(seq)-len(hi): return pi 
    return rselect(hi,i-(len(seq)-len(hi)))
from random import choice
def random_partition(seq):
    pi =choice(seq)
    lo=[x for x in seq if x<pi]
    hi=[x for x in seq if x>pi]
    return lo,pi,hi

def test_rselect(seq,i):
    print 'Sequence',seq
    stat=rselect(seq,i)
    print 'Statistic', stat
```

Comment: That was a great solution,considering it does only a few changes to my approach . However I dont think its helping when there are duplicate entries, does it?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you cared about duplicate entries. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now could you explain the rationale behind using `if len(seq)<=i` instead of 1.? I used `1`earlier for the function to exit the loop if the size of the sequence was = 1 element.

Comment: I assumed that this was kind of an "exception throw": it handles the case where there are not enough elements in seq for it to contain an i-th one. But I don't see any particular reason for returning the whole seq in this case, it's just that it's what you did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your algorithm is your determination of `loc_pi`. For example, consider the case where 1000 is the first `pi` chosen in `loc_pi=seq.index(pi)`. In that case, `loc_pi` will equal 2 since 1000 is at index 2 of the sequence, and the function will return 1000, which we know is absolutely not order statistic 2.

Thus, we know we can't determine `loc_pi` based on the index of the randomly chosen `pi`. After all, that list is in an arbitrary order- its position means nothing. What you are actually trying to get for that `loc_pi` value is *the number of elements in that sublist that are below your chosen pi*. And thankfully, that is easy to get! Just change the line:

```
    return lo,pi,hi,loc_pi
```

to

```
    return lo,pi,hi,len(lo) + 1
```

And you'll find it performs correctly and consistently!

```
dynamic-oit-vapornet-c-913:test dgrtwo$ python test21.py
Sequence [54, -1, 1000, 565, 64, 2, 5]
Statistic pi 565
Location 3
pi 5
Location 5
pi -1
Location 0
pi 2
Location 0
2
dynamic-oit-vapornet-c-913:test dgrtwo$ python test21.py
Sequence [54, -1, 1000, 565, 64, 2, 5]
Statistic pi -1
Location 1
pi 54
Location 0
pi 5
Location 2
pi 2
Location 0
2
```

ETA: Please also note that your algorithm as written will *not* always work if there are ties in the input sequence. Try a few examples and you will see what I mean. There are simple ways to solve it that I am sure you can figure out.

Comment: I havent been  able to test your suggestion yet, but out of curiosity shouldnt we return len(lo)+1, instead of len(lo), to include the pivot element as well?

Comment: Quite right; I was thinking of indexed by 1 for some reason. Fixed (though now it will give a different output, I don't have the chance to change that)

Comment: :I tried to run to run the code with your suggestion but I get a totally weird output for instance with the input ` test_rselect([54,-1,1000,565,64,2,5],2)` I get :`@ubuntu:~/py-scripts$ python Dselect.py
Sequence [54, -1, 1000, 565, 64, 2, 5]
Statistic pi 54
Location 0
pi -1
Location 1
-1
`.Which really doesnt serve the purpose. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

If you change:

```
return lo,pi,hi,len(lo)+1
```

to:

```
return lo,pi,hi,len(lo)
```

and add a closing bracket `)` so that the syntax error is corrected, like so:

```
lo,pi,hi,loc_pi= random_partition(seq)
```

It will work reliably for sequences with no repeated entries:

```
for i in xrange(1,8):
    print rselect([54,-1,1000,565,64,2,5],7,i),
#Output:
-1 2 5 54 64 565 [1000]
```

Which is the expected output.

I guess my main advice would be to try and code following the [style guidlines!](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Your code is pretty tricky to read at a glance!

The parameter `length` is redundant, so can be removed altogether. And also sometimes the last entry would be returned as a single value list, so I've changed that (although it will know fall over if you pass it an empty list, probably not a big deal). Here is the code in slightly more readable format, with a correction to allow for repeated entries:

```
from random import choice, shuffle

def rselect(seq, i):
    lo, hi, pi, loc_pi = random_partition(seq)
    if loc_pi == i or (min(lo) == max(lo) and not hi):
        return pi
    elif loc_pi > i:
        return rselect(lo, i)
    elif loc_pi < i:
        return rselect(hi, i - loc_pi)

def random_partition(seq):
    pi = choice(seq)
    lo = [x for x in seq if x <= pi]
    hi = [x for x in seq if x > pi]
    return lo, hi, pi, len(lo)

#this is a nice way to test it:
cat = range(1,21)
for i in xrange(1,21):
    shuffle(cat)
    print rselect(cat,i),

#Output:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: I dont really think it solves the problem. I dont see the statistic printed as a result. Could you elaborate what your solution does? I tried it using my input sequence , the solution works in some cases and doesnt in others for instance `test_rselect([54,-1,1000,56,5,64,2,5],3)`  returns an IndexError on line `if loc_pi>i:return rselect(lo,loc_pi+1,i) `. Do improve your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @KodeSeeker - I've updated to allow for repeated elements in the input sequence (thats what the problem was with: `[54,-1,1000,56,5,64,2,5]`).

Comment: What does your input sequence really do ? I dont see what happens with `rselect(cat,i)` there .Could you please explain the test function?

Comment: @KodeSeeker - Sure. First we create a list of numbers, 1 to 20 (its nice to use numbers that are in a sequence and the same as the expected output i value, as it means we can see if the code is working easier). Then we shuffle this list, so it is in a random order. Then we perform `rselect` on it, to return the ith element. We do this over all possible i, and each time `cat` is shuffled differently, so its quiet a good test (I think - although it doesn't have repeated elements, so I missed that issue..). another cool way to do it would be to put `print rselect(cat,i) == sorted(cat)[i-1]`.

Comment: I think we're not on the same page. I expect the **ith order statistic** to be printed. When I run your code I only get an ordered list instead. I'm a noob to Python, am I missing something here?

Comment: @KodeSeeker - The `ith order statistic` is the output of `rselect` right?

Comment: @KodeSeeker - exactly. the output calls rselect 20 times, and prints the ith statistic for each value its called with.

Comment: @KodeSeeker - great :) I find it easier to think of the `ith statistic` as `the ith element in the sorted list`, which is why i made a test like that